# How do I convert datetime to date?

Tags: mysql

I've got this SQL and my table is `DATETIME`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rapport WHERE user_checkin LIKE '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-%' ";
```

What I want is convert that to just give me the date so far I've tested

`CAST`, `DATE`, `DATE_FORMAT`. with no success.

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understood the question and you want to get only a date as a result, you should use `date` in query:

```
SELECT date(ColumnName) FROM rapport WHERE user_checkin LIKE '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-%' ";
```